# composer require designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport not installing in laravel8

Tags: laravel-8

composer require designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport --ignore-platform-reqs
Using version ^2.0 for designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport[v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.1] require illuminate/support ^5.5 || ^6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^8.69).
- Root composer.json requires designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport ^2.0 -> satisfiable by designmynight/laravel-mongodb-passport[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.